# how to convert function base api views into class base api views?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

In my project, I have the following 4 APIs (function base API view)

```
save_user()
login_user()
get_user_info()
update_user()
```

I want to convert it into class base API view

```
class UserApi(APIView):

  def post():
    #save user
 
  def get(): 
    #for get user info

  def put():
    #for update user info
```

so how to use login() in class base views.
OR use function base view for login?

to use a mixture of class based API view and function base API view in a single views.py file is good or bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To login, the user has to provide the username and password. This will be a HTTP post request. You can create a class-based view only for post for login and define the URL endpoint.

```
class Login(APIView):
   
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # authentication related code
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', Login.as_view()),
]
```

The main advantage of using class-based views is to separate the HTTP methods (get, post, put, delete) and write re-usable code. DRF provides generic class-based views that can be used for common functionality with less code.

For the login functionality, having a class-based view is useful if you have token based authentication. Since, you haven't mentioned about it, I would say having class-based views for both `login` and `user` will be good for consistency and readability. There is not rule that you can't mix class-based and function-based views; it depends on what you are trying to achieve and one is not necessarily good or bad over the other.

Comment: class Login(APIView): having only one method or API is a good idea? What is the benefit of using class base API view instead of a function-based API view for the above example?